# What's the purple thing on Yu-Gi-Oh's head?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I've always wanted to know what the purple thing on Yu-Gi-Oh's head is.

- It's not really on his head, it's behind it, so it might not qualify as a hat
- It looks solid, so maybe it's not his hair.
- it seems to be coming from inside his jacket so it's probably not the collar.

Does anyone know what it is?

Can / does he ever take it off?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's his hair.

[image]

The drawing seems to illustrate quite well that the purple block originates from the nape of his neck.

[image]

In this image, specifically the bottom half, you can see really clearly that the purple block starts on his neck. Look closely at the middle drawing in the second half of the image. You can see the it follows the natural hairline of almost everybody and is not stuck onto the collar, the side profiles show too much of a natural hairline for me to believe and this is a hat.

> Yami Yugi's hair features multiple layers including long blond crocked, pointy locks for his fringe. Unlike Yugi, some of the blond locks jut upwards. The rest of his hair features five large spikes colored black with red (with a hint of magenta) rims all along the edges.

From [yugioh wiki](http://yugioh.wikia.com/wiki/Yami_Yugi)

Comment: Well that's your job as the guy posting an answer. That's how it works

Comment: @Daft Edited, and continuing to find more evidence.

Comment: Also I was more asking what proof you wanted, but sure be snide.

Comment: Why would you ask _what proof_ someone wanted? Any sort of proof as long as it's proof. That's how proof works.

Comment: Now that's some top-notch proof!